# Geiger Count Plot in same axes

Tags: plotting

I have 3 plots of a Geiger count made in these parameters

minute by minute

hour by hour (60min/60min)

day by day (1440min/1440min)

I got this pic with this code

```
SetDirectory["D:\\Documents and \\Settings\\Física\\Desktop\\Pesquisa\\Dados_Chuva"];
data = Import["geiger_2015_06_30_ita.txt", "Table"];
values = data[[;; , 2]];
ticks = data /. {x_, _} :> 
   StringInsert[StringTake[#, {7, 10}] &@ToString[x], ":", 3]
f = Interpolation[values];
n = Length[data];
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, n}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[n], Rotate[#, -45 Degree] & /@ ticks}], 
   Automatic}, ImageSize -> 500]
a = Join[{data[[1]]}, data[[60 ;; ;; 60, ;;]]]
b = data[[;; ;; 1440, ;;]]
values = a[[;; , 2]];
ticks = a /. {x_, _} :> 
   StringInsert[StringTake[#, {7, 10}] &@ToString[x], ":", 3]
f = Interpolation[values];
n = Length[a];
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, n}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[n], Rotate[#, -45 Degree] & /@ ticks}], 
   Automatic}, ImageSize -> 500]
values = b[[;; , 2]];
ticks = b /. {x_, _} :> 
   StringInsert[StringTake[#, {7, 10}] &@ToString[x], ":", 3]
f = Interpolation[values];
n = Length[b];
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, n}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[n], Rotate[#, -45 Degree] & /@ ticks}], 
   Automatic}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

And the pic

[image]

Now, I need to put these 3 plot in only one plot with different colors.

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you want is `Show`:

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x,0,10}]
plot2 = Plot[Cos[2 x] + 1, {x,0,10}, PlotStyle -> Orange]
Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note that the styling of each graph is inherited from each of the individual plots you made;  so you have to use `PlotStyle` in the original plotting command to change the colors.